# Replace NGINX 403 for deny with a different error response code

Tags: nginx, http-response-codes

```
location ~* ^/(jmx-cons|web-console|debug|invoker)/ {
deny all;
}
```

I have looked over the documentation but I cannot find a way to replace the 403 with a different response code.  I have tried using the error_page directive and it doesn't complain on config check but it doesn't effectively change the response code.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the error_page directive does work for this purpose, I was just doing it wrong.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you exactly want, but if all you want is denying all and showing a different status code ( not 403 ) you can use `return` instead, for example: ( returning 500 )

```
location ~* ^/(jmx-cons|web-console|debug|invoker)/ {
    return 500;
}
```